# Unable to clone using git-tfs (migration from tfvc to git)

Tags: git, migration, tfvc

I'm trying to migrate 300GB file from tfvc to git using git-tfs but its behaving in a very different way, like it clone upto 120Gb and then clone size start reducing to 98gb. I want to know is their any cloning size limit for such migration?

I used this:-
git tfs clone $repo $Branch $local
its cloning but behaving differently as mention above

Comment: I'm one of the dev of git-tfs and I really don't get what you want to express with these numbers. Git store data differently and more efficiently so that's normal that it takes less space. And during the process, git-tfs use a temp folder which is cleaned so the decrease could be normal. Give better information : errors, logs, missing changesets or branches,... because nothing is alarming with what you shared...

Comment: And there are 'git gc' that happen some time to time that optimize data (pack) stored data and could reduce also the repository size. So to see if migration is a success you will have to rely more on data migrated analysis than repo size....